# SandboxInfo tooling api

Tags: sandbox, tooling-api

Hi I was wondering if anyone has started to use the new winter 16 and the API to refresh sandboxes.

In the winter 16 tooling API, it says there is a new object called SandboxInfo, but if i use workbench in my sandbox which is on winter 16 I do not see this object?

Comment: what version of org did you sign up, i started looking at my developer org and realized that I do not have sandbox (silly me) later went to na14 and then realized they are not on winter 16. so unless you have a enterprise org with sandbox option I feel that the 2 objects cannot be queried / described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) records only appear within the Production Org that spawned the Sandbox. The Sandbox itself can't see the record.

You would also need to be using v35.0 or later of the API to access it.